# Why I can't type in PyCharm (all Jetbrain products) terminal with powershell core?

Tags: powershell, pycharm, powershell-core

I can't type in PyCharm (all Jetbrain products) terminal with powershell core, but no problem in Windows Terminal or VSCode's teminal (the same start cmd `C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe -nolog`).

It was working fine before but not (only Jetbrain products) after I installed MSYS2 via choco.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem, hope to help the next people.
Since Powershell has posh-git installed and only works with Git for Windows, I installed the GNU version of Git at the same time, causing this problem.